# MATLAB - histograms of equal size and histogram overlap

Tags: matlab, histogram

An issue I've come across multiple times is wanting to take two similar data sets and create histograms from them where the bins are identical, so as to easily calculate things like histogram overlap.

You can define the *number* of bins (obviously) using

```
[counts, bins] = hist(data,number_of_bins)
```

But there's not an obvious way (as far as I can see) to make the bin size equal for several different data sets. If remember when I initially looked finding various people who seem to have the same issue, but no good solutions.

Comment: Aren't you describing [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html)? `hist` is based on `histc`. Also, you can use `hist` with columns of data to vectorize it, e.g., `hist(rand(1e3,3))`.

Comment: I mean, sure, if you're into easy, quick and robust solutions, but who wants that when you can spend significantly more effort and time coupled to a heuristic which may introduce bias!?

Answer (score 0):

### The right, easy way

As pointed out by horchler, this can easily be achieved using either `histc` (which lets you define your bins vector), or vectorizing your histogram input into `hist`.

### The wrong, stupid way

***I'm leaving below as a reminder to others that even stupid questions can yield worthwhile answers***

I've been using the following approach for a while, so figured it might be useful for others (or, someone can very quickly point out the correct way to do this!).

The general approach relies on the fact that `MATLAB`'s `hist` function defines an equally spaced number of bins between the largest and smallest value in your sample. So, if you append a start (smallest) and end (largest) value to your various samples which is the min and max for *all* samples of interest, this forces the histogram range to be equal for all your data sets. You can then truncate the first and last values to recreate your original data.

For example, create the following data set

```
A = randn(1,2000)+7
B = randn(1,2000)+9

[counts_A, bins_A] = hist(A, 500);
[counts_B, bins_B] = hist(B, 500);
```

Here for *my specific* data sets I get the following results

```
 bins_A(1)   % 3.8127  (this is also min(A) ) 
 bins_A(500) % 10.3081 (this is also max(A) )
 bins_B(1)   % 5.6310  (this is also min(B) )
 bins_B(500) % 13.0254 (this is also max(B) )
```

To create equal bins you can simply first define a min and max value which is slightly smaller than both ranges;

```
topval = max([max(A) max(B)])+0.05;
bottomval = min([min(A) min(B)])-0.05;
```

The addition/subtraction of `0.05` is based on knowledge of the range of values - you don't want your extra bin to be too far or too close to the actual range. That being said, for this example by using the joint min/max values this code will work irrespective of the A and B values generated.

Now we re-create histogram counts and bins using (note the extra 2 bins are for our new largest and smallest value)

```
[counts_Ae, bins_Ae] = hist([bottomval, A, topval], 502);
[counts_Be, bins_Be] = hist([bottomval, B, topval], 502);
```

Finally, you truncate the first and last bin and value entries to recreate your original sample exactly

```
bins_A = bins_Ae(2:501)
bins_B = bins_Ae(2:501)
counts_A = counts_Ae(2:501)
counts_B = counts_Be(2:501)
```

Now

```
bins_A(1)     % 3.7655
bins_A(500)   % 13.0735
bins_B(1)     % 3.7655
bins_B(500)   % 13.0735
```

From this you can easily plot both histograms again

```
bar([bins_A;bins_B]', [counts_A;counts_B]')
```

And also plot the histogram overlap with ease

```
bar(bins_A,(counts_A+counts_B)-(abs(counts_A-counts_B)))
```